# add a bigInteger value to a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, integer, biginteger

The code below does not work because it does calculations with negative numbers using modulo. So I have to parse the values to the 2d array declared as BigInteger instead of an int.

```
BigInteger  bi2, bi3;
    int det=(key[0][0] * key[1][1])-(key[0][1] * key[1][0]);

    BigInteger  bi1 = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(det));
    bi2 = new BigInteger("26");
    bi3 = bi1.modInverse(bi2);
    int inverse= bi3.intValue();
    key[0][0] = inverse * key[0][0];
    key[0][1] = inverse * key[0][1];
    key[1][0] = inverse * key[1][0];
    key[1][1] = inverse * key[1][1];

    key2[0][0] = key[1][1];
    key2[1][1] = key[0][0];
    key2[0][1] = -key[0][1];
    key2[1][0] = -key[1][0];
```

the problem is here:
it print wrong answer for each calculation because it needs to use o BigInteger instead of inetger because of negative values.

```
key[0][0] = key2[0][0] % 26;
key[0][1] = key2[0][1] % 26;
key[1][0] = key2[1][0] % 26;
key[1][1] = key2[1][1] % 26;
```

Also after that I want to make some calculations with this BigIntegers. However the calculations will include just integers. so after that I have to convert those BigIntegers in the array to integers.

the rest code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        for (int j =0; j<  alphabet.size() ; j++){
            if (alphabet.get(j) == str.charAt(i)) {
                    int index = alphabet.indexOf(str.charAt(i));
                    store.add(index);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(store.toArray()));

    for (; k<store.size(); k++){
            sp2 = sp +1;
            int n2=0;
            int n1 = 0;
            if (sp==store.size()-1){
                n1 = store.get(sp);
                if (sp2> store.size()-1){
                  n2 = 23;  
                }
                if(sp2 < store.size()) {
                    n2 = store.get(sp2);
                }
                fn1 = ((key[0][0] * n1) + (key [0][1] * n2))% 26;
                fn2 = ((key[1][0] * n1) + (key [1][1] * n2))%26;
                conversion.add(fn1);
                conversion.add(fn2);
                sp+=2;
            }
            if (sp > store.size() -1){
                    break;
                }
            else{
                n1 = store.get(sp);
                n2 = store.get(sp2);
                fn1 = ((key[0][0] * n1) + (key [0][1] * n2))% 26;
                fn2 = ((key[1][0] * n1) + (key [1][1] * n2))%26;
                conversion.add(fn1);
                conversion.add(fn2);
                sp+=2;
            }           
    } 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(conversion.toArray()));

    List<Character> encrypted = new ArrayList();

    for (int i=0; i<conversion.size(); i++){
        int num = conversion.get(i);
        char letter = alphabet.get(num);
        encrypted.add(letter);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(encrypted.toArray()));
```

error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -8

the error is this(4 lines before the end):
    char letter = alphabet.get(num);

Comment: Provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you bother reading the documentation?

Comment: + So at least the types of keytest and myInteger. As well as the exact error you're facing. And start with http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_valueof.htm

Comment: it is 100 lines code. thought that will be confusing reading through 100 lines of code

Comment: The "M" in "MCVE" stands for "minimal", not for "dump your whole code". And please add the error message.

Comment: You need 500 lines of code to add a BigInteger to an array?

Comment: Your variable `myInteger` is unknown where you like to access it. So check where you declare that variable and if it really should be accessible.

Comment: You should also fix your error message, then you post your original code, since there is no `myInteger` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those with a maths background it is a surprising feature that

```
 System.out.println("=" + (-3 % 4));
```

for example, returns -3 instead of 1 (which would be in the range [0,3]);

Edit:

in other words, the error message

```
error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -8
```

is ultimately caused by (n % m) can return negative values. A statement like

```
num=(26+num)%26;
```

would cure it.

Comment: I love those me-too-downvotes without giving any hint on why, just because the question has been downvoted and the social instinct triggers the mouse-button?

Comment: I'm not the voter, but I don't see where this answers OPs question.

Comment: @Tom: the error is quite obvious from the error message ... I added this to my answer just 2 minutes before your comment. Can you see it now more clearly?

Comment: You mean two minutes after my comment :p. But yes, that is better.

Comment: @Tom, won't start a quarrel about that, but as of the latest update of my screen it tells me that my edit was 8 minutes ago whereas your comment was 9 minutes ago. Anyway, even by 5 minutes distance I would consider that as "at the same time" ;-)

Comment: Yes your edit is fewer minutes ago, it means, it is younger :P. And yes, it doesn't matter much :).

Comment: @Tom main thing is that you see my point, hope others will see it, too.

Comment: @ChristosMichael I guess you just don't have a lot of experience with java error messages. **I** do have a lot. Guess why my pseudonym is *Gyro Gearlose* ;-)

Comment: @GyroGearloose I know what the problem is. If you go through my code you will see that some negative numbers are added in the key2 array. Then a calculation using the mod 26 takes place where this calculation provides wrong answer because of the use of int. This adds wrong value to the table so when am using this: char letter = alphabet.get(num); to get the write letter from the alphabet list can't take the correct value In here have to use BigInteger to solve this error. The questions is how do I insert BigIntegers to an array. That was my question at first.

Comment: @ChristosMichael not ***all***, at least not me. Using BigInteger for a range of 26 (or let it be 26 squared) is an overkill. Every change of BigInteger requires a new Object to be created. That is costly in terms of performance, and as far as I have seen your code, completely unnecessary. Integer/int will do perfectly.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Don't care about performance on this program. It is a uni  lab. However how can I use this: num=(26+num)%26; and where? I did not understand.

Comment: @ChristosMichael just between your lines int num = conversion.get(i);
        char letter = alphabet.get(num); It would be better to *normalize* the values before they get into *conversion*, but as performance doesn't matter, this is the most obvious place. Can't take any guaranty if this solves your project completely or removes only the topmost error.

Comment: @GyroGearloose oh it works. Thank you sooo much. Could you please explain me better why I should do that. Because i did not get the meaning?

Comment: @ChristosMichael As you have seen (n%m) can be negative. In math, *n mod m* is either seen as a relation between fairly abstract classes, or a cast into the integer range [0,m-1]. In java, the range preserves the sign, and such is [(-(m-1),m-1]; You need a stronger mapping to [0, m-1], which is accomplished  by n=(n+m)%n;

Comment: @ChristosMichael please give me feedback if my explanation is good enough for you or if you need more input, For I had 2 zorkmids lost for trying to be helpful and while this answer is present, it is bait for the me-too-downvoters, so I consider to delete this answer to recover the lost 2 bits.

Comment: @GyroGearloose just vote you? Or can i write something somewhere?

Comment: @ChristosMichael I had a look on your previous questions and you seem unfamiliar with the concept of "accepting an answer". So please, go through all your previous questions and if any of the answers did answer your question, there is some suspiciously looking hook right below the "upvote" "count" "downvote" buttons. This can only be done on one answer per question. I urge you to please have a look on how stackoverflow works. This would be a profit for all of us.